How to make a parameter typed but optional in TypeScript
I'm trying to make a parameter optional in my function and TypeScript is throwing an error.
Example code:
showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback: Function = null) {
       
}

Typescript error:
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Function'.ts(2322)

Callback is optional. How do I avoid this error?

There's a difference between an optional parameter and a parameter that is potentially null.
For an optional parameter, implicitly typed as T | undefined, you would write:
showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback?: Function) {}

Optional parameters have to be placed at the end of the parameter list, i.e. they cannot be followed by required parameters.
For a parameter that can be null, you would use a union type:
showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback: Function | null) {}

Which you can also give the default value of null:
showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback: Function | null=null) {}


For completeness, it might be worth pointing out that optional parameters are typed as T | undefined. It's subtle but can make a big difference if you're expecting nullables

You do not need to use Null to define optional parameters. Instead of that Typescript that "?" to define any variable, the parameter is optional.
Example 1: Using arrow functions with optional.
function showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback?: ()=>{}) {
       
}

Example 2: With a return type for the function
function showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback?: () => void): void {
 
}

Example 3: Using function keyword
function showDialog(title: string, value: string, callback?: Function) {

}

